# At least one positive constant in linear dependance

Tags: linear-algebra

In linear dependance of $x_{1},..,x_{n}$ there is a nontrivial
linear combination of these vectors that is zero. Thus there are constants
$ c_{1},..,c_{n} $ at **least one of which is positive** such that
$$c_{1}x_{1} + c_{2}x_{2} + · · · + c_{n}x_{n} = 0 $$
Why can't all of the constants be negative? I ve seen this assumption in many proofs.

Comment: If they are all negative, change their sign. What is important is: they they are not all zero.

Comment: Even more generally, the scalar field could be one in which "positive" and "negative" don't make sense to talk about in which case the phrase should be replaced by "**at least one of which is nonzero**."  For example, if the scalar field were $\Bbb C$.

Answer (score 0):

They could be negative, for instance choose

$$x_1=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    1 
  \end{bmatrix}
$$
and 
$$x_2=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    -2 \\
    -2 
  \end{bmatrix}
$$
Obviously, they are linearly dependent. As you say, you could choose $c_1 = -2$ and $c_2 = -1$. But this is not the only choice, actually and $c_1,c_2$ satisfying $$c_1 - 2c_2 = 0$$ would do. What they're saying is that you could always choose $c_1 \ldots c_n$ in a way such that at least one is positive. Actually you could always fix a $c_k$ and compute the rest. Choose $c_1 = 1$, you get $c_2 = \frac{1}{2}$.